# Why does this error 1066 show up from join statesment

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, tablegateway

I have yet another issue. I am trying to join 2 tables so that i can pull data from both. I am new to TableGateway and am having issues finding the same situation. I have a page that will pull blogs by state and i also have a state table. I want to join these using state_id and show "state" from state table on the page. Below is what i have. Not sure if i am even using the right code!

Model - From StateTable:

```
public function getState($state)
{
$sqlSelect = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();
$sqlSelect->columns(array('state_id'));
$sqlSelect->join('states', 'states.state_id = state_id', array('state'), 'inner');

$statement =   $this->tableGateway->getSql()->prepareStatementForSqlObject($sqlSelect);
$resultSet = $statement->execute();
return $resultSet;
```

}

Model from PostTable:

```
   public function getbystate($state_id)
   {
    $state_id  = (int) $state_id;
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('state_id' => $state_id));

    return $rowset;
   }
```

Controller action:

```
 public function ListAction()
 {
  $state_id = $this->params()->fromRoute('state_id');
  $state = $this->params('state');
  $list = $this->getPostsTable()->getbystate($state_id);
  $states = $this->getStatesTable()->getState($state);
  $view = new ViewModel(array(
    'list' => $list,
    'states' => $states,
  ));

  return $view;  
 }
```

Update 8:41 EST 06/06/2017

I put the join in the Posts module instead of in the States Model. 
I have gotten rid of the errors however I still need to know how to show the state. Everything above is the same except it resides in the posts module.

The "View" is below - it errors 
Notice: Undefined property: Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result::$state in /var/www/html/module/Blog/view/blog/list.phtml on line 6

View:

```
 $title = 'My Blog';
 $this->headTitle($title);
 ?>
 <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
 <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($states->state);?></td>
 <table class="table">
 <tr>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>View</th>
  <th>Comments</th>
  <th>Post Date</th>

 </tr>
 <?php foreach ($list as $posts) : ?>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <a href="/Blog/view/<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($posts->post_id);?>">
     <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($posts->post_title);?>
   </a>
 </td>
 <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($posts->num_views);?></td>
 <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($posts->num_comments);?></td>
 <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($posts->post_date);?></td>

 </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 </table>
```

Added tables 12:01 EST 06/07/2017
 Post Table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `posts` (
 `post_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `state_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `post_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `post_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('deleted','draft','inactive','active') DEFAULT 'inactive',
 `activate_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_hot` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
 `ordering` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `num_views` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `allow_comment` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `num_comments` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `picLink` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `description` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `food` enum('Yes',' No') DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
 KEY `idx_latest` (`status`,`activate_date`),
 KEY `idx_latest_category` (`state_id`,`status`,`activate_date`),
 KEY `idx_most_commented` (`state_id`,`status`,`num_comments`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `idx_most_viewed` (`state_id`,`status`,`num_views`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `idx_most_viewed_2` (`status`,`num_views`),
 KEY `idx_created_user` (`created_user_id`,`post_id`)
```

States Table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `states` (
 `state_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `state` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`state_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Your sql query for joining two tables is not right. Would you be able to show up your `blog` and `state` table please?

Comment: @J.Sajeeb I have added the tables to the post. Perhaps the indexing is not quite correct either. When i did a dump i was supprised at all the keys. I dont remember doing all that. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to join `posts` and `states` tables to show **state** according to your `list.phtml`. You are trying to output **state** there like `$states->state` therefore, this is completely outside loop. So you need to fetch an object from which you can output state the way you wanted. Make another method in the `StatesTable` model to get it worked. See the following

```
public function getStateById($state_id)
{
    $state_id  = (int) $state_id;
    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('state_id' => $state_id));
    $row = $rowset->current();

    if (!$row) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not find row $state_id");
    }

    return $row;
}
```

And `getbystate($state_id)` method from `PostsTable` model should be unchanged like you wrote above. `listAction()` method should be the following

```
public function ListAction()
{
    $state_id = $this->params()->fromRoute('state_id');

    $list = $this->getPostsTable()->getbystate($state_id);
    $states = $this->getStatesTable()->getStateById($state_id);

    $view = new ViewModel(array(
        'list' => $list,
        'states' => $states,
    ));

    return $view;  
}
```

Now as I told your sql query for joining two tables was not right, that would like this

```
public function getState($state)
{
    $state = (string) $state;
    $sqlSelect = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select();

    // Specify columns from 'posts' table
    $sqlSelect->columns(array('post_title', 'description', 'etc'));

    // Here you can specify columns for 'states' table
    $sqlSelect->join('states', 'posts.post_id = states.state_id', array('state', 'etc'), 'inner');

    // Apply conditions here
    $sqlSelect->where(array('states.state' => $state));

    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($sqlSelect);      

    return $resultSet;

}
```

This method has a limitation. You cant convert this resultset object to array because of result-set prototype issue. But this will work somehow.

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You are always welcome! Do not forget to vote the answer further if I can help you! :)

Comment: I tried to vote but it wont let me because my reputation is under 15. I do have another open issue. I believe that i will have many before this project is done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=ZF2AuthAcl%20Module%20doesnt%20work%20out%20of%20the%20box thanks again!